# JSON data to Google sheet

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a JSON link who is giving me data like -

```
"data": [{
    "name": "123Seguro",
    "domain": "123seguro.com",
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "123seguro"
  }, {
    "name": "Earn.com",
    "domain": "21.co",
    "id": 2,
    "slug": "earn-com"
  }, {
    "name": "2C2P",
    "domain": "2c2p.com",
    "id": 3,
    "slug": "2c2p"
  }, {
    "name": "4thWay",
    "domain": "4thway.co.uk",
    "id": 5,
    "slug": "4thway"
  }, {
    "name": "51credit.com",
    "domain": "51credit.com",
    "id": 6,
    "slug": "51-credit-card-manager"
  }, ........................................
```

Is there is a way to take these data to Google sheet in 4 columns as it is giving 4 column data?

I tried with a script like this -

```
function fetch() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('mylink.json');
  var res1 = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(res1);
  var name = json["name"];
  Logger.log(name);

}
```

But it is not reading the data and logger returning "UNDEFINED". can somebody help here, please.
**Edit-1**
On a small research, I found a script like this -

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    //Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

Here I am applying the formula like this - =IMPORTJSON("https://theAPILINK.json","data")
And the response is like 
0
1
2
3
4
.
.
.......And at the moment I am changing from "data" to "name" it is showing "Node Not Available".

Any suggestions, please. :)

Comment: Have you tried `name = json[0]["name"]`? as the json records are in an array?

Comment: Yes Eineki, it is returning the error like this - TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from undefined.

Comment: @6797023 and what do you get when logging your variable `json`? I suggest logging it to Stackdriver so you can interact with its structure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's important to understand your JSON data structure:

```
Data
-> 0
-> -> Name: 123Seguro
-> -> Domain: 123seguro.com
-> -> id: 1
-> -> slug: 123seguro
-> 1
-> -> Name: Earn.com
-> -> Domain: 21.co
-> -> id: 2
-> -> slug: earn-com
-> 2
....
```

So to reach your data, you'll always need to first open `data` and then select a specific "row".

```
function fetch() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('mylink.json');
  var res1 = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(res1);
  var name = json["name"];
  Logger.log(name);

}
```

> But it is not reading the data and logger returning "UNDEFINED". can somebody help here, please.

This is because you first need to open `data` as explained above. Then define the item of which you want to know the name. Try something like `Logger.log(json["data"][0]["name"])`. This should return the name of the first item in your JSON response.

> Here I am applying the formula like this - `=IMPORTJSON("https://theAPILINK.json","data")` And the response is like 0 1 2 3 4 . . .......And at the moment I am changing from "data" to "name" it is showing "Node Not Available".

So you tell the function where to find your data and the root node (`data`). When you change `data` to `name` it is unable to find an element called like that. So it will return the error you've mentioned.

I would recommend to dive into your first fetch example instead of using the other function. It'll help you to understand the mechanism and process the data as you require.

Comment: Thanks Casper, Now I am able to take these data to my sheet. :)